# Screen Flow - values not refreshed when opening the flow a second time

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a pretty basic screen flow with a picklist component and an email one to send an email with an InvocableMethod. Everything works fine but when the user fills up the form once, close the flow and open it again, the picklist and email values aren't update, meaning if the user selects whatever value he wants, the flow keep the values from the first attempt and never update it with the new values selected in the following attempts. i've never experience this behavior, i checked the winter 24 release note but i didn't find anything that could explains it (the new functionnality Refresh Values Between Screens for More Components doesn't apply here).

Does anyone has experienced this behavior ? Any help appreciated!

Comment: is there anything issue related to browser? can you try in some other window or browser?

Comment: I just tried with firefox (instead of chrome) but same issue. The flow kept the value selected in Chrome. @sanket kumar

Comment: Can you edit your question and update with more details like how you have configured your input elements on screen? Are you doing any action on load of the screen flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sanketkumar i found the issue. I update the triggering record during the process and to get the updated values a get record is needed which i didn't know.